# R function to check what it is wrong when two factor variables do not have the same level

Tags: r

I was wondering if one of you knows a function that tells you why the two objects does not match.

Indeed, I would like to compare two variables that deal with the same kind of variable (municipalities), unfortunately one of them has more levels than the other. Therefore, I would like to know which municipalities is included is only one of them (as I have more than 900, I would prefer not looking at it one by one)

Here is my code:

```
depext <- ifelse(EMQmetro$MUNI==EMQmetro$V08C_1, "same","diff")

*Error in Ops.factor(EMQmetro$MUNI, EMQmetro$V08C_1) : 
  les niveaux des facteurs diffèrent*

identical(EMQmetro$MUNI, EMQmetro$V08C_1, num.eq = TRUE, single.NA = TRUE, attrib.as.set = TRUE,
          ignore.bytecode = TRUE, ignore.environment = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
 *[1] FALSE*
```

Thank you in advance for your future help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns are `factor` class.  For `==` to work, it should be converted to `character` class

```
 ifelse(as.character(EMQmetro$MUNI)==as.character(EMQmetro$V08C_1), "same","diff")
```

The `identical` would be `FALSE` if we have at least a difference in one level.  Sometimes, there will be unused levels in one column that will create the issue.